# Does Minnesota Statutes 43A.11 apply at the County or Council Or Regional level?

Tags: employment, minnesota, government

I am a US Army Veteran and I applied to a few jobs position at the County and Regional/Council government agency level. I was told by the HR department that [MN Statutes 43A.11](https://www.revisor.mn.gov/statutes/cite/43a.11) (which gives preference to hiring military veterans in some circumstances) doesn't apply at those levels.

Is that true or am I being lied too?

I tried researching online but can't really find much information. This law does fall under 2023 Minnesota Statutes > State Employment > Chapter 43A. So maybe HR is telling the truth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapter 43A of the Minnesota Statutes governs the civil service hiring system of the Minnesota state government. *See* [here](https://www.revisor.mn.gov/statutes/cite/43A.01). These positions are either part of the executive branch of state government or the judicial branch, which are [defined as follows](https://www.revisor.mn.gov/statutes/cite/43A.02):

> Subd. 22.Executive branch. "Executive branch" means heads of all
> agencies of state government, elective or appointive, established by
> statute or constitution and all employees of those agency heads who
> have within their particular field of responsibility statewide
> jurisdiction and who are not within the legislative or judicial
> branches of government. The executive branch also includes employees
> of the Department of Iron Range Resources and Rehabilitation. **The
> executive branch does not include agencies with jurisdiction in
> specifically defined geographical areas, such as regions, counties,
> cities, towns, municipalities, or school districts, the University of
> Minnesota, the Public Employees Retirement Association, the Minnesota
> State Retirement System, the Teachers Retirement Association, the
> Minnesota Historical Society, and all of their employees, and any
> other entity which is incorporated, even though it receives state
> funds. . . .**
>
> Subd. 25.Judicial branch. "Judicial branch" means all judges of the
> appellate courts, all employees of the appellate courts, including
> commissions, boards, and committees established by the supreme court,
> the Board of Law Examiners, the law library, the Office of the State
> Public Defender, district public defenders and their employees, all
> judges of all courts of law, district court referees, judicial
> officers, court reporters, law clerks, district administration
> employees under section 484.68, court administrator or employee of the
> court in a judicial district under section 480.181, subdivision 1,
> paragraph (b), guardian ad litem program employees, and other agencies
> placed in the judicial branch by law. Judicial branch does not include
> district administration or public defenders or their employees in the
> Second and Fourth Judicial Districts, court administrators not under
> section 480.181, subdivision 1, paragraph (b), or their staff under
> chapter 485, or other employees within the court system whose salaries
> are paid by the county, other than employees who remain on the county
> payroll under section 480.181, subdivision 2.

This statute does not apply to local governments or other independent governmental agencies that are not part of the system. Some local governments may have hiring preferences for military veterans, but if they do, this would be as a result of local ordinances, and not a result of this particular state law.